# Remove layers and objects in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

My question is, how to remove object and layer in same time using fabricJS delete function?

Here is my jQuery for deleting objects:

```
$('#remove').on('click', function () {
    deleteObjects();
    $(".deleteBtn").remove();
});
```

Here is my FabricJS example with layer control https://jsfiddle.net/peLcju2h/15/

Thank you :)

Comment: And your deleteObjects() function does what, exactly? You've posted a code snippet above, but that code isn't actually in your fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look through the Fabric JS documentation you'll notice that every object extends the `Fabric.Object`.

The `Fabric.Object` has a `remove()` method that you can call to remove any `Fabric.Object` or class that extends `Fabric.Object`, which is just about every class that can be rendered onto a canvas, with the exception of a handful of less commonly used classes.

Take a look at the documentation of the `remove()` function here:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#remove

Also there is a hierarchy of classes on the main page of their documentation which can be found here:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/